# Deep copy Objective-C objects with UIImageView as property

Tags: objective-c, deep-copy

I have an object with properties that are NSString, UIImageView and simple vars like BOOL, int and float.

I'm trying to create a deep copy of the object. For that I've implemented the NSCopying protocol to my class and the copyWithZone method like:

```
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    iItem *clone = [[iItem alloc] init];

    //iItem *clone = [super copyWithZone:zone];

    clone.originalTransform = self.originalTransform;
    clone.initialTransform = self.initialTransform;
    clone.originalFrame = self.originalFrame;

    clone.zOrder = self.zOrder;
    clone.itemId = self.itemId;
    clone.itemIdColor = self.itemIdColor;
    clone.itemIdTexture = self.itemIdTexture;
    clone.itemIdStyle = self.itemIdStyle;
    clone.textureLevel = self.textureLevel;
    clone.currentSizePercent = self.currentSizePercent;
    clone.holdItem = self.holdItem;
    clone.isInverted = self.isInverted;
    clone.delegate = self.delegate;
    clone.mergedFrame = self.mergedFrame;

    clone.selectedMergeView = [self.selectedMergeView copy];

    clone.ScaleFactorScreen = self.ScaleFactorScreen;

    clone.selectedFrameView = [self.selectedFrameView copy];
    clone.selectedFrame = [self.selectedFrame copy];
    clone.frameBeforeMovement = self.frameBeforeMovement;

    //clone.touchBeginPoints = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    clone.touchBeginPoints = CFDictionaryCreateMutableCopy(NULL, 0, self.touchBeginPoints);

    clone.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    clone.animationImages = self.animationImages;
    clone.image = [self.image copy];
    clone.animationDuration = self.animationDuration;
    clone.animationRepeatCount = self.animationRepeatCount;
    [clone startAnimating];


    clone.transform = self.transform;

    clone.frame = self.frame;

    clone.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    clone.multipleTouchEnabled = YES;

    return clone;
}
```

The class iItem inherits from UIImageView class, so I tried to call super copyWithZone but I'm getting error. And for the UIImageView objects that I'm trying to clone I receive the SIGABRT message '-[UIImageView copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x210f50'.

How can I make a deep copy of an object that have UIImageViews, NSString and simple vars?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're doing everything right, perform the 'copy' selector on objects that implement `NSCopying`, and manually set properties (like you did for image, content mode etc) for those that don't.

Comment: But when is executed the first copy over an UIImageView, I'm receiving a SIGABRT message.

Comment: What is the error? You can only call copy on YOUR descendent classes, not on a generic UIImageView....

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to archive with NSKeyedArchiver and unarchive to NSKeyedUnarchiver assuming your objects conform to NSCoder

Comment: UIImageView doesn't conform to NSCoder.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly initiate with this

```
iItem *clone =[[iItem allocWithZone:zone ] init];
```