# Store an object into NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Please, correct me, where i'm wrong (i'm a begginer)
I want to store a class objects into NSArray. For example:

```
MySimpleClass *mscObj = [[MySimpleClass alloc] initWithSomething:@"something"];
NSMutableArray *myarr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[myarr addObject:mscObj];
mscObj = @"somethingelse";
```

And then my myarr index 0 change from @"something" to @"somethingelse". Why? Can i store a copy only to array?

EDIT:
In MySimpleClass:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MySimpleClass : NSObject {
}

@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *objectName;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *objectTarget;

-(void)addName:(NSString*)name;
-(void)addTarget:(NSString*)target;


@end
```

.m file

```
#import "MySimpleClass.h"

@implementation MySimpleClass

@synthesize objectName;
@synthesize objectTarget;

-(void)addName:(NSString*)name{
    self.objectName = name;
}

-(void)addTarget:(NSString*)target{
    self.objectTarget = target;
}

-(void)flushAll {
    self.objectTarget = nil;
    self.objectName = nil;
}

@end
```

Then In other class i have:

```
   MySimpleClass *mscObj = [[MySimpleClass alloc] initWithSomething:@"something"];


 [myarr addObject:[mscObj copy]];

        int testunit = [myarr count];
        for(int i=0;i<testunit;i++) {
            MySimpleClass *myelement = [myarr objectAtIndex:i];
            NSLog(@"%@ : %@",myelement.objectName,myelement.objectTarget);
        }
```

Comment: u changed the value of mscObj and NSArray store only refence of object. ur myarr index 0 refer to same object where object value has been changed. if u want that ur index at 0 should have "something" and at index at 1 it should be "somethingelse" then u have to keep copy of object at index 0 and then add updated copy of mscObj to index 1 by using addObject: method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
[myarr addObject:[[mscObj copy] autorelease]];
```

Comment: After this I'm getting an error: [mscObj copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. Should I write method copy in my class? But what should i put there?

Comment: No need to write any methods, the above code should work just fine. Where are you placing your code? Is your object a Core-Data object?

Comment: What is `listElements`? It doesn't show up anywhere in your code.

Comment: Sorry, i've tried different class, and copy old version. Post updated.

Comment: I'm right now fix error by add <NSCopying> @protocol to class, but still don't have a copy in index 0. Still is the last motified version on my class instance.

Comment: OK, i'm write a empty method copy in mysimpleclass, and it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Given the code you've posted, the first object (index 0) in the array won't change due to the fourth line, `mscObj = @"something else";`. That line changes the value of the pointer `mscObj` itself, so that it'll point to a completely different object. If the object in the array is changing, I believe that the real code you're using won't quite match what you've posted -- please check that.

However, if you use the `mscObj` pointer to change an *attribute* of the object that it points to, then you'll have changed the object in the array:

```
mscObj.something = @"somethingelse";
```

Here you're changing the `something` *property* of the object that `mscObj` refers to, but you're not changing the value of `mscObj`. This *will* change the contents of the object in the array, since that's the same object that `mscObj` points to.

Comment: Yes, you're right, Sorry, i don't think this is something different. I add code to my original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you do this

```
[myarr addObject:mscObj];
```

myarr is retaining a reference to mscObj. So any time mscObj is changed myarr will reflect that change.

When you do this

```
[myarr addObject:[mscObj copy]]; // I've left the autorelease out for simplicity
```

myarr retains a reference to a new copy of mscObj. When mscObj is then updated myarr will not reflect the change because it's reference points to a completely different object.

EDIT

For copy to work your class ** MySimpleClass** needs to implement NSCopying. See this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459598/how-to-copy-an-object-in-objective-c) answer for help on that.

Comment: As i said below: After this I'm getting an error: [mscObj copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. Should I write method copy in my class? But what should i put there?

Comment: For copy to work correctly - you need to look up **NSCopying** - which is the protocol ** MySimpleClass** needs to implement for method calls such as **copy** to work.

Comment: I add this, now, compile without error, but still i don't have a copy of instance in my array. So problem still exist.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the pointers. Your object at index:0 remains at the same location in the memory.It will always change.

try releagind the mscObj after adding the array and create a new MySimpleClass object with @"somethingelse"

Answer (score 0):

mscObj is a reference and what the array stores are references. So if you manipulate a object from outside the container the reference reflects the changes. Think about the by value by reference difference.