# Draggable UIImageViews copies

Tags: ios, objective-c, drag-and-drop, uiimageview

I need to make an exact copy of subclassed UIImageView that has drag and drop enabled, so I can drag it but leave a copy to replace it or simply making a copy that I can drag to another place instead of the first one.

Some screenshots to explain:

Before dragging

[image]

Dragging:

[image]

As you can see I'd like to leave the cupcake in place so I can keep dragging multiple copies from it.

---

Nevermind... I figured out! How? I made another instance inside de subclassed UIImageView, copied every property (UIImage, delegate, frame) added it to the same superview and used a protocol to pass it to the UIView I need it...

SOLUTION:

The code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DragAndDrop.h"

@interface DraggableImageView : UIImageView

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <DragAndDrop> delegate;

@property CGPoint startLocation;
@property (strong, nonatomic) DraggableImageView *copied;

@end

#import "DraggableImageView.h"

@implementation DraggableImageView

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    self.copied = [[DraggableImageView alloc] initWithImage:[self image]];

    [self.copied setDelegate:[self delegate]];
    [self.copied setFrame:[self frame]];

    [[self superview] addSubview:self.copied];

    CGPoint pt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.copied];

    self.copied.startLocation = pt;

    [[self.copied superview] bringSubviewToFront:self.copied];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user taps on the cupcake just create a new UIImageView, and copy it from the one that's already on screen.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement NSCopying in that class, here is a link to another post on how to do this: [another stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459598/how-to-copy-an-object-in-objective-c)

In that post the copywithzone method that you will use are basically instructions on how to make a copy of your class.

In the area of your code that detects when a user touches/drags that image, make a copy of it using the above described method, set its proper frame x and y position, then add it as a subview to the view that was holding the original object.

```
//Somtheing like this
myCustomObject *object2 =[object copy];
object2.frame = cgrectmake.....
[view addSubview:object2];
```