# How to pass NSObject from one view controller to another

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, copy, automatic-ref-counting, nsobject

I am using iOS 5 SDK with arc. I want to pass `NSObject` from VC1 view controller to VC2 view controller, do modification and put back into VC1 controller. I don't want to point same nsobject from both VC1 and VC2 controllers. Whenever I am passing nsobject, it should create a copy of that nsobject and do the modification. (Do not modify actual nsobject).

I have tried below code but it crashes and giving error as

**-[ImageObject mutableCopyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1364ec20**

**Code:**

**I have NSObject as :**

```
@interface ImageObject : NSObject
@property (copy,nonatomic) NSString *path;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite) int id;
@end
```

**In VC1 view controller:**

I am passing my nsobject to VC2 view controller as follows:

```
VC2ViewController *vc2 = [[VC2ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC2ViewController" bundle:nil];
vc2.imageObj = [imgObj mutableCopy];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
```

**In VC2 view controller:**

VC2ViewController.h file

```
#import "ImageObject.h"
@interface VC2ViewController : UIViewController
@property (retain,nonatomic) ImageObject *imageObj; 
@end
```

VC2ViewController.m file

// modifying nsobject as below

```
-(void)modifyObject
{
UIViewController *previousViewController = [self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.viewControllers.count-2];
        if ([previousViewController isKindOfClass:[VC1ViewController class]])
        {
            VC1ViewController *parent = (VC1ViewController *) previousViewController;
            if(parent != nil)
            {
                _imageObj.id = 2;
                [parent reloadData:_imageObj];
            }
            parent = nil;
        }
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Have any idea ? How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ImageObject` class needs to conform to the `NSCopying` Protocol.
This [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1459674/1262527) explains better and shows you how the code looks like.

I also think that you need to use `[imgObj copy]` instead of `[imgObj mutableCopy]` because according to apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSMutableCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

The NSMutableCopying protocol declares a method for providing mutable copies of an object. 
**Only** classes that define an **“immutable vs. mutable”** distinction should adopt this protocol. 
Classes that don’t define such a distinction should adopt NSCopying instead.

Comment: Hi Mariam, Thank you for answer. I read about NSCopying Protocol. Also looked difference between copy and mutableCopy from here (http://sarojsblog.blogspot.in/2011/07/difference-between-copy-and-mutablecopy.html). As per I understood that if i use copy, then both arrays will point on same address, but if i use mutableCoopy instead of copy then both arrays will have different addresses. So, which protocol should i use? NSCopying or NSMutableCopying

Comment: You should be using NSCopying unless your ImageObject has two types immutable and mutable which I think is not the case here. The post talks about the difference between a normal NSArray and a NSMutableArray these are 2 different types of object classes...much like a normal string and mutable string.

Comment: From a logical point of view I see why you see it makes more sense to use mutableCopy (you can change the contents of your object) but the point here is there is **NO Immutable Version** of your class...hence, no "immutable vs. mutable distinction" therefore..." adopt NSCopying instead."