# How to perform a Objective-C deep copy

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloning

Does the Objective-c copy method do a **deep copy** of an object?

```
NSObject *clone = [self copy];
```

Comment: You may try NSKeyArchiver https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html this will help.

Comment: the models usually are kind of NSDictionary or NSArray. Let me know if you are looking for creating a deep copy for these data types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSObject *clone = [self copy];
```

Wont perform deep copy but would be a shallow copy.

You need to implement NSCopying protocol like this

```
//ContactCard.h
@interface ContactCard : NSObject<NSCopying>
{
    NSString* name;
    NSString* email;
}
...
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone;
@end

//ContactCard.m
@implementation ContactCard
...
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    ContactCard* cc = [[ContactCard allocWithZone:zone]init];
    cc->email = [email copy];
    cc->name = [name copy];
    return cc;
}
...
@end
```

You can read more on [enter link description here](http://iosbasics.tumblr.com/post/79958273591/assign-vs-shallow-vs-deep-copy)
Or refer Apple [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) on NSCopying

Comment: That's not a deep copy; it fails to copy any subclasses of ContactCard or any external resources it may access (for example: this code would not copy an instance of an AVAssetReader object, but, rather, the pointer—that's shallow, not deep). Grossly insufficient answer.

Answer (score -3):

this might be help. For deep copy of any custom object we need to adopt NSCopying protocol in that class.
[How to copy an object in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459598/how-to-copy-an-object-in-objective-c)