# Copy custom class object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, copy

I have a custom class which has got some properties. And I want to copy an object of this class so I get second object with the same content.
Example:

```
MyCustomClass *objectName = [[MyCustomClass alloc] init];
// fill here with some properties
objectName.propertyOne = @"smth";
objectName.propertyTwo = @"smth";
// And copy my object
MyCustomClass *secontObject = [objectName copy];
```

Does there exist something like "copy" method?

Note: the real copy method which is already built in didn't help.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/ObjectCopying.html

Comment: In order for the `copy` method to give useful results you need to implement the `copyWithZone:` method in `MyCustomClass`. That will be called by `copy`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [the friendly documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/ObjectCopying.html), found via [a search for "copying"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/search/index.php?Search=copying) in Apple's docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing built in. The NSCopying protocol is included for this, but since it's just a protocol, you have to implement the copying logic yourself.

Comment: Ok, It seems I should write this logic for every class which's objects I need to copy. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To use *copy* method you first need to implement NSCopying protocol for your custom class:

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject <NSCopying> 

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *string;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *number;

@end


@implementation SomeClass

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone*)zone
{
     SomeClass *copyObject = [SomeClass new];
     copyObject.string = _string;
     copyObject.number = _number;

     return copyObject;
}

. . . . . . .

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a copy of a custom class.  You'll need to implement copy logic yourself.

See [How to copy an object in objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459598/how-to-copy-an-object-in-objective-c)

Comment: If you find another question that you believe answers this one, please flag the question for a moderator or vote to mark this as a duplicate rather than posting just a link. That allows solutions to a single problem to aggregate in one place, increasing their findability.

Comment: Thanks Josh.  Will do in the future.