# modifying copy of array object affect object stored in the array

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have object copying issue.

```
@property (nonatomic,strong)ITEM *editingItem;
self.editingItem= nil;
self.editingItem = [[self.ItemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1] copy];
self.editingrowIndex = indexPath.row;
```

When I assign some object to editingItem in didselect table row and start editing it in textfield delegates when i change the object property values then it is changning in the object stored in an array.but i want only editingItem object should have new values.But without updating array new values are getting stored from editingItem to object in the array.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459598/how-to-copy-an-object-in-objective-c) this may what you are looking for

Comment: What is the object in `self.ItemsArray` and does it conform to the `NSCopying` protocol?

Comment: why do you use copy of object instead of direct pointer to original one?

Comment: @heximal Presumably because he wants the user to edit the item and have the option of cancelling the edit.

Comment: @trojanfoe you are correct.

Comment: OK that's cool, but can you please answer my first question?

Comment: @trojanfoe yes,its superclass confrims to nscopying

Comment: Not the same thing.  There is your issue; you aren't copying the object at all.

Comment: @trojanfoe every class need not confirm to NSCopying,my superclass confirms to nscoying and i am inheriting that class means all the methods will be copied into my subclass right

Comment: It depends what instance variables the subclass adds over the superclass.  None of those instance variables will be copied.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51171/discussion-between-narasimhaiah-kolli-and-trojanfoe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation provided by the OP, in the other answer is incorrect, as it does not copy the instance variables; rather it creates another reference to them.  This would explain the issues the OP is seeing in his question (where that code should have been presented, and not in a separate answer).

Here is a better implementation:

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    Item *copy = [[Item allocWithZone:zone] init];

    copy->_nombre: [_nombre copy];
    copy->_linea = [_linea] copy];
    copy->_tags = [_tags copy];
    copy->_htmlSource = [_htmlSource copy];

    return copy;
}
```

Note that the instance variable copy statements provided in the other implementation is correct (aside from the missing `copy` call), but it won't work for private instance variables (a common occurrence), so I always stick to the form `copy->_instanceVariable = [_instanceVariable copy];`.

Also note that if the object derives from something other than `NSObject` then first statement should be:

```
Item *copy = [super copyWithZone:zone];
```

instead of:

```
Item *copy = [[Item allocWithZone:zone] init];
```

Further notes:

I find it highly suspect that you are keeping `NSMutableString` objects as instance variables.  That is fairly unusual in my experience, having only used them as temporary objects for building immutable strings.  I suspect you are not using the correct data type to hold this data.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Item : NSObject <NSCopying>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *nombre;//nombre del medicamento
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *linea;//linea a la que pertenece
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableString *tags;//palabras por las que se puede encontrar en el buscador
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *htmlSource;//código html para mostrar su contenido
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableString *obj;

-(id) copyWithZone: (NSZone *) zone;

@end


@implementation TempObject


-(id) copyWithZone: (NSZone *) zone
{
    Item *copy = [[Item allocWithZone: zone] init];

    [copy setNombre: self.nombre];
    [copy setLinea: self.linea];
    [copy setTags: self.tags];
    [copy setHtmlSource: self.htmlSource];

    return copy;
}
```

Override CopywithZone method in your item class and set each and every property inside that method.It is the solution for copying object.When you do allocwithzone and init,the new object is created with new address and old values which you have to set manually in copywithzone: method.So duplicate instance with old values.It is perfect solution working for me.

Comment: The total Description exists here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459598/how-to-copy-an-object-in-objective-c

Comment: Is this an answer? It looks like it should be part of your question, or it needs more explanation.

Comment: @jrturton it is solution

Comment: @jrturton If it is not solution.. then please give me solution.I too don't know it worked this way.. if anything is wrong i will correct it.

Comment: Makes more sense now you've added some explanation!