# Unable to save data in NSUserDefaults with crash with Signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to save `NSData` in `NSUserDefaults` in a loop, but I'm constantly getting an error.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *index = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"alltweetsoftrend%d", i];
[defaults setObject:tweetData forKey:index];

[defaults synchronize];
```

Where `i` is index of the loop, it means key is not null in any case. I have also checked my `NSData(tweetData)` and this also is not null. I am just getting this error in saving.

Comment: So what does the exception text say?

Comment: does your `tweetData` confirm to NSCopying protocol. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459598/how-to-copy-an-object-in-objective-c

Comment: @trojanfoe Signal SIGABRT EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Comment: That's not the exception text.  iOS will have generated a `NSException` with an explanation of the issue.  I assume you are running this inside Xcode?

Comment: NSUserDefaults is for storing small amounts of data.  Have you tried writing this to a file and putting the file name in NSUserDefaults?  NSData has a writeToFile method.

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes running on Xcode

Comment: your `tweetData` data need to copy on userdefault, so required to implement it. Implement that protocol or convert your `tweetData` into NSData, NSString etc.

Comment: @CharlesA. No i didnt tried. I have saved even MBs in Nsuserdefaults but now its just some Bytes that are unable to store

Comment: @JackSparrow Tweetdata is NSdata

Comment: Update the question with the code where you are defining/setting the tweetData/ NSData

Comment: @Xcoder I am simply storing NSData using async requests in other activity and i have checked that tweetdata is not empty or corrupt. I am recieving user tweets in that and im sure NSdata is not empty.

Comment: Ok. Just wanted to make sure that you are not equating the tweetdata to an array or dictionary from the response.

Comment: No, Response comes in NSdata and i can convert into Nsdictionary or NSarray with successful results but unable to store it for further usage.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2315972/653513

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with your code. There's a slight chance the NSData is too large to store, but I wouldn't really expect a SIGABRT in that case. The most likely issue is that the NSData was created with `[NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:length:]` and the buffer that the NSData pointed to was deallocated. There could be other issues that cause the problem as well, such as using a shared NSData global variable between threads, incorrect typecasting from CFDataRefs, etc, etc.

Try writing a different NSData and see if it works. For example:
`NSData *tweetData = [NSData dataWithBytes:"Hello" length:6];`. I bet that works, so the problem has to do with how your tweetData was created and sent into this code.

Comment: Yes! Size of NSData was large. I have done that by storing That into a file in document directory.